# С++ Работа с указателями на функции, разными типами данных

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели, типы-данных

Здравствуйте. Согласно заданию, я создаю указатели на функции следующего вида:

```
int (*func1)(int *);
int (*func2)(int *, float *);
int (*func3)(void *);
float (*func4[N])(double, double, double);
```

Их нужно использовать для вызова функций, которые вычисляют значения выражений. 
Для последнего массива указателей на четвертую функцию нужно использовать `switch()`.
Во время компиляции (в CodeBlocks) ошибок нет. А вот во время выполнения (после ввода индекса указателя в массиве указателей) программа выдаёт ошибку.
Также непонятно, почему переменная с приобретает значение 0.
Код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int func_a(int*);
int func_b(int*, float*);
int func_c(void*);

float func_H(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return 2 * a + 3 * b + 4 * c;
}
int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int (*func1)(int*);
    int (*func2)(int*, float*);
    int (*func3)(void*);
    float (*func4[N])(double, double, double);
    func1 = func_a;
    func2 = func_b;
    func3 = func_c;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        func4[0] = func_H;

    double a, b, c, H;
    int x, x1;
    float x2, x3;
    int* px, *px1;
    float* px2;
    void* px3;
    px = &x;
    px1 = &x1;
    px2 = &x2;
    px3 = &x3;
    cout << "Введите значение x (int): ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Введите значение x1 (int): ";
    cin >> x1;
    cout << "Введите значение x2 (float): ";
    cin >> x2;
    cout << "Введите значение x3 (float): ";
    cin >> x3;
    a = (double)(*func1)(px);
    cout << "\nЗначение переменной a: " << a << endl;
    b = (double)(*func2)(px1, px2);
    cout << "\nЗначение переменной b: " << b << endl;
    c = (double)(*func3)(px3);
    cout << "\nЗначение переменной c: " << c << endl;
    int index = 0;
    cout << "\nВведите индекс указателя на функцию в массиве:";
    cin >> index;

    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
            H = (*func4[0])(a, b, c);
            break;

        case 1:
            H = (*func4[1])(a, b, c);
            break;

        case 2:
            H = (*func4[2])(a, b, c);
            break;

        case 3:
            H = (*func4[3])(a, b, c);
            break;

        case 4:
            H = (*func4[4])(a, b, c);
            break;

        case 5:
            H = (*func4[5])(a, b, c);
            break;

        case 6:
            H = (*func4[6])(a, b, c);
            break;

        case 7:
            H = (*func4[7])(a, b, c);
            break;

        case 8:
            H = (*func4[8])(a, b, c);
            break;

        case 9:
            H = (*func4[9])(a, b, c);
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Значение индекса должно находится в интервале [0; 9]";
            break;
    }

    cout << "\nЗначение функции H: " << H << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int func_a(int* px)
{
    return (int) pow(*px, 2) + pow(*px, 3);
}

int func_b(int* px1, float* px2)
{
    return (int) log(abs(*px1)) - pow(*px2, 4);
}

int func_c(void* px3)
{
    int* Px3 = static_cast<int*>(px3);
    return (int) pow(cos(*Px3 - 4.0), 2);
}
```

Буду очень рада скорому фидбеку. (:

[image: Выполнение программы и окно с ошибкой]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, не

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    func4[0]=func_H;
```

а

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    func4[i]=func_H;
```

?

Comment: Да, спасибо. Буквально только что исправила. Вот только значение 'с' остаётся нулевым. Ломаю голову теперь над этим.

Comment: Тоже мне бином Ньютона :)     `return (int) pow(cos(*Px3-4.0), 2);` Косинус у вас какое значение может принимать? От -1 до 1. А в квадрате? От 0 до 1. А привести к целому (отбросить дробную часть)? только 0 (вряд ли вы так угадаете со значением x3, чтоб получить косинус, равный 1...)

Comment: Логично. Ещё раз благодарю за помощью.

Comment: @Настя Шпит, у   Harry  всегда все логично...